# Equations involving logarithms without calculator

Tags: logarithms

I am doing a course where we are not allowed to use a calculator and I find equations with logarithms rather tricky. Here's an example question:

Solve the following equation for $x \in \mathbb{R}$:

$\log_3(1 + 10x) = 4$

Apologies if I am not adhering to the community guidelines with this "no clue" type of question but I am unable to find any helpful sources for this.

Comment: Hint : $g(x)=3^x$ is the inverse of $f(x)=\log_3(x)$

Comment: Use the formula :
$$\log_3 (x) = y \Rightarrow x = 3^y$$

Answer (score 3):

Let's solve a similar problem: $$\log_5(1+3x)=2.$$
In order to get rid of the $\log_5$ on the LHS, we apply $\exp_5$ on both sides:
$$\exp_5(\log_5(1+3x))=\exp_5(2).$$
Since $\exp_5$ and $\log_5$ are *inverse functions* of one another, they cancel each other out on the LHS. Further, on the right, we obtain $\exp_5(2)=5^2=25$. We're left with $$1+3x=25.$$ Solving for $x$ yields $x=8$.

**Important:** Logarithmic functions only allow for positive arguments. In this case, we must thus have that $1+3x>0$, that is, $x>\frac 13$. Our solution $x=8$ satisfies this condition. If it didn't, the equation would have been impossible, i.e., the set of solutions would have been empty.

Now it's your turn.